# Get facebook pictures for later use

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, objective-c-blocks

So, I'm trying to get all the facebook pictures I'm tagged so I can see them on the iPad, but I wanted to make this function so I can call it everytime I would need to get the url's. The problem is, after I call this function, the array is nil, because the values I get are inside a block. How do I make an array to store the data I get for later use?

```
-(NSArray *)getFacebookTaggedPictures
{
__block NSArray *taggedPictures = [[NSArray alloc]init];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
     if(!error)
     {
         taggedPictures = [(NSArray *)[result data]copy];
         //NSLog(@"the tagged pictures are: %@",result);
     }
 }];
return taggedPictures;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly noticed, the array that you return is empty because your method returns before the response from the API has been received and parsed into `taggedPictures` inside the `completionHandler` block.

You must save the array inside that block. I'd recommend changing your method as follows:

```
-(NSArray *)getFacebookTaggedPicturesWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray* photos))completion;
```

where the calling methods would pass the appropriate completion block to handle the obtained pictures. (i.e. save them to disk, display them, do some processing on them etc.):

```
void (^loggerBlock)(NSArray* photos) = ^(NSArray *array) {
    NSLog(@"obtained photos: %@",[array description]);
    //save here instead of logging
};

[self getFacebookTaggedPicturesWithCompletion:loggerBlock];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do I save there? I don't know how to write the code to make it happen, those blocks are getting the better of me

Comment: You can use the same code you use elsewhere. Just be careful if you're using CoreData for persistence: `NSManagedObjectContext` is not thread-safe.

Comment: I'm not using Core Data, I don't need to, just want to have an array with the data I get from this method.